# Entity Framework (6.x), Computed Columns and INotify

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using a DB First implementation of Entity Framework and I've run into an issue with a need for a computed column and the interaction with a view...

Scenario:

User has FirstName and LastName.  In a listbox I want to use a display name generated from FirstName and LastName.  Generally, simple enough.  The issue comes from when either the first name or last name gets edited.  I've extended my entities with INotifyPropertyChanged and implemented that in the T4 template.  I extended the User entity to create a DisplayName property.  In the View I use a CollectionViewSouorce based on the DisplayName.

The issue comes in when a user's name is edited, but no notification occurs because the change is made to either FirstName or LastName, not DisplayName.  So the CollectionViewSource is never getting a change notification for DisplayName.

I could, manually, add an OnPropertyChanged("DisplayName") to the User entity in the FirstName and LastName properties, but that would be overwritten next time I update my model from the DB.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks.

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record...

I went with a partial class extension and just programmatically triggered OnPropertyChanged for the DisplayName whenever the constituent properties were changed and saved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for one of the following options:

- create `partial class User` to your `User` entity with `OnFirstNameChanged`,`OnLastNameChanged` methods implemented in it, the class remains unchanged when you re-generate classes from model.
- handle `context.ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged` event of your ObjectContext
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
- adjust the t4 template(based on your question you know how to deal with it) to call custom method when `FirstName` and `LastName` property setter is generated.